# network interfaces and IFF_XX flags

Tags: network-programming, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I would like to understand if there are any conventions set up in kernel programming when creating network interfaces in the kernel and initializing interface flags, such as IFF_UP, or IFF_MULTICAST etc. What flags must be configured at minimum -- is there any requirement for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html, which is the man page for NETDEVICE(7).  In there, you will see a list of flags under SIOCSIFFLAGS and SIOCCIFFLAGS.

Answer (score 0):

`Standard interface flags` are described at [include/linux/if.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/if.h#L30).

See comments for details.